# Try to install Homebrew and got syntax error

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew

Try to run brew_instal.sh

''' /bin/bash ./brew_instal'''

**'/brew_instal: line61: syntax error near unexpected token '{**

**'/brew_instal: line61: 'have_sudo_access() {**

Here are the lines in brew_intal.sh

```sh
tty_mkbold() { tty_escape "1;$1"; }
tty_underline="$(tty_escape "4;39")"
tty_blue="$(tty_mkbold 34)"
tty_red="$(tty_mkbold 31)"
tty_bold="$(tty_mkbold 39)"
tty_reset="$(tty_escape 0)"

have_sudo_access() {
  if [[ -z "${HAVE_SUDO_ACCESS-}" ]]; then
    /usr/bin/sudo -l mkdir &>/dev/null
    HAVE_SUDO_ACCESS="$?"
  fi

  if [[ -z "${HOMEBREW_ON_LINUX-}" ]] && [[ "$HAVE_SUDO_ACCESS" -ne 0 ]]; then
    abort "Need sudo access on macOS!"
  fi

  return "$HAVE_SUDO_ACCESS"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need root permission.

Have you try :

```
sudo /bin/bash ./brew_instal
```